# Throughput upper limit formula, not giving expected result

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am using a formula from a paper to find the throughput upper limit across a computer network
however my calculation gives a different answer to what is given in the paper. Below are the parameters and the formula used:

Parameters for 802.11B

[image: parameters for 802.11b]

Throughput upper limit formula

[image: Throughput upper limit formula]

The answer stated in the paper when LData is 1000 is 11.49, however the answer i continue to get is 10.58.

Could anyone shed any light on how to get the correct answer?

Comment: I get with all these: $\dfrac{8000}{159.5}=50.1567398$? So, do I have to do some conversions or _just_ plug in the parameters in the  formula?

Comment: did you use the 802.11b parameters? there are parameters for both 802.11a and 802.11b in the table.

Comment: I used the first set of parameters...

Comment: sorry it was the second set, i should have been specific.

Comment: I think I am getting the answer 10.58. I'll write the answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll write out the parameters set of 802.11B separately for convenience

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline T_P & 144 \mu s\\ T_{PHY} & 48 \mu s \\ \tau & 1 \mu s \\ T_{DIFS} & 50 \mu s\\ T_{SIFS} & 10 \mu s\\ CW_{min}&31\\ T_{slot} & 10 \mu s\\ \hline \end{array}$$

Along with this we also have $L_{DATA}=1000$. So, let's compute the quantity $TUL$:

1. Numerator is easy to compute: $8L_{DATA}=8000$.
2. Denominator is the following expression:

\begin{align*}
&2T_P +2 T_{PHY}+2\tau+T_{DIFS}+T_{SIFS}+\frac{CW_{min} T_{Slot}}{2}\\&=2\cdot 144+2 \cdot 48+2 \cdot 1+50+10+\frac{31\cdot 20}{2}\\&=288+96+2+50+10+310\\&=756
\end{align*}

So, the final thing is $$TUL=\frac {8000}{756}=10.5820106\cdots$$

which means you're right or the recipe we are working with is wrong!

Comment: That is exactly how i worked it out, though I'm still confused how the author of the paper has come to get 11.49.

Comment: What's his answer with parameter set 1?

Comment: The first set of parameters gives the result 50.2 which is what you first calculated. So assuming you used to the same calculation for both sets of parameters this should work.

Comment: So, then, he has a typo in his paper or something then?

Comment: I would hope not, it was published in the IEEE communications letters.

Comment: Not sure what to say now. :)

Comment: Me neither, can have the accept for helping as you have.